# Drop foreign key mechanism in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a foreign key reference to another table

```
CREATE TABLE `redirector_logs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `redirector_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `redirector_logs_redirector_id_foreign` (`redirector_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `redirector_logs_redirector_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`redirector_id`) REFERENCES `redirectors` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

When I drop the foreign key 'redirector_logs_redirector_id_foreign', constraint is dropped but the key still remaining.

Please tell me why and how to remove the whole foreign key (including the key and the constraint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key which you have created is actually an index and it is independent of the foreign key which you created.

To drop the key `redirector_logs_redirector_id_foreign` you need to execute

```
DROP INDEX `redirector_logs_redirector_id_foreign` ON `redirector_logs`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So that means when I want to drop a foreign key constraint I have to execute 2 separate drop command to drop the constraint and drop the index key, right? And there is no way to drop it all at once...

Comment: Yes, you need to drop the index as well as the constraint and there is no single command to do both at same time

Answer (score 0):

have you checked drop foreign key with if exist option like
IF(OBJECT_ID('FK_constraint_name', 'Foreign Key Constraint') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Constraint_name
END
Possibilities why FK is unable to drop :
-It is possible that child table contains data which is yet not deleted 
-Not deleted Index
-Another schema also has reference of this FK
-Innodb internal data dictionary is out of sync with the mysql one you can check the status of InnoDB using "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS"